# Handling the HTMLParser.HTMLParseError exception, and test case

Tags: python, exception, html-parsing

I am working on a python script where I use data from a HTML file. I use the HTMLParser module, with my own handle_endtag and so on, as described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

When handling exceptions, I am looking at handling the HTMLParser.HTMLParseError exception. Yet I cannot make a test case where the parser throws an exception! Two questions:

Is the parser so good at parsing anything that handling the exception is useless?

Can someone cook up a test input that makes the parser throw the exception ? (I want to see what it looks like!)

Poor, tortured, parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLParser.HTMLParseError is raised on broken markup and in some cases when it encounters an error while parsing.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

parser = HTMLParser()

parser.feed('<![..]>')
```